# Sorting an array by and keep the order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have data like this:

```
var data = [
  ['a', 2010], ['a', 2011], ['a', 2012],
  ['b', 2010], ['b', 2012], ['b', 2013],
  ['c', 2010], ['c', 2011], ['c', 2012],['c', 2013]
]
```

and I want sort this array by year but keep the order of data, so the output would be:

```
var data = [
  ['a', 2010], ['b', 2010], ['c', 2010], 
  ['a', 2011], ['c', 2011], 
  ['a', 2012], ['b', 2012], ['c', 2012],
  ['b', 2013], ['c', 2013]
]
```

As you can see, every data (a, b, c) does not always have data of each year (like b for 2011 or a for 2013)

If I use `sort()` function, it does sort by year but not in order.

```js
var data = [
  ['a', 2010], ['a', 2011], ['a', 2012],
  ['b', 2010], ['b', 2012], ['b', 2013],
  ['c', 2010], ['c', 2011], ['c', 2012],['c', 2013]
]
var newData = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1]
})
    
  console.log(newData)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You seem to want to sort on two parameters rather than "keeping the order".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an expression to deal with *ties*: if `a[1] - b[1]` is zero, you should specify that then the order is determined by the first element:

```js
var data = [
  ['a', 2010], ['b', 2011], ['c', 2012],
  ['b', 2010], ['b', 2012], ['b', 2013],
  ['c', 2010], ['c', 2011], ['c', 2012],['c', 2013]
]
var newData = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1] || a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
});
      
console.log(newData)
```